# Django ORM. Check that sum of additional field of m2m relation model equals 100

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to implement a check on this relation, to ensure that all ticket's weight in sum gives me 100.

```
class PortfolioTicker(models.Model):
    """
    Helper model for M2M relationship between Tickers and Portfolios
    """

    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, models.PROTECT, related_name="tickers")
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Ticker, models.PROTECT)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.portfolio} {self.ticker} {self.weight}"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a report for each ticker:

```
x = PortfolioTicker.objects.values('ticker').order_by('ticker').annotate(summa=Sum('weight')).annotate(hundert=Case(When(summa=100, then=True), default=False))
```

if you want to check for a given ticker

```
PortfolioTicker.objects.filter(ticker=given_ticker).aggregate(summa=Sum('weight'))['summa']
```

Comment: Actually, I implemented the method `create_portfolio(self, portfolio_tickets)`, which calculates the sum of PortfolioTicker before saving it to DB.